# Handling none fatal exceptions from COM api's

Tags: c#, exception, com

I have the following code snippet which calls a COM interface api (MS Mobile API)

```
try
{
    MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
    IMbnInterfaceManager infMgr = (IMbnInterfaceManager)mbnInfMgr;

    IMbnInterface[] interfaces = (IMbnInterface[])infMgr.GetInterfaces();
    ///
    /// NOTE: Will throw exception here if no Adapter Present - "Service not Started"
    ///
    foreach (IMbnInterface mobileInterface in interfaces)
    {
        MBN_INTERFACE_CAPS caps = mobileInterface.GetInterfaceCapability();
        MBN_READY_STATE readyState = mobileInterface.GetReadyState();
        IMbnRadio radio = (IMbnRadio)mobileInterface;

        MBN_PROVIDER provider = mobileInterface.GetHomeProvider();
        ///
        /// NOTE: Will throw exception here if no SIM Present.
        ///
```

The COM Exceptions are handled as below

```
///
/// Handle COM Exceptions 
///
catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
{
    switch ((uint)ex.ErrorCode)
    {
        case 0x8054820A:
             // ...
             break;

        case 0x80070490:
             // ...
             break;

             default:
             string str = "COM: " + ex.Message;
             break;
    }
}
```

The issue I have is that not all exceptions to my mind are are fatal, as in the 'No SIM' exception and I still require 
to access the COM interface components that have been created, but the exception terminates all those instances.

How should I go about this, or do I have to go through the construtor processs again ?

Thanks for any advice

Sarah T

Comment: Well, catch the exception and set a "SimIsMissing" variable to true.  Then avoid making any calls that require the SIM to be present.  You probably want to make that obvious to the user by disabling toolbar buttons and menu items.  If that still leaves you with a program that's usable then you're ahead.  If not then there wasn't much point in catching the exception.

Comment: What do you mean by "the exception terminates all those instances"? If you handle the exception, you can't use the references any more?

Comment: Thanks Guys, and yes Simon your correct that I can not use those references any more and that is my problem, how would I get around the issue? I still need to reference the instances after the exception is thrown. This happens for many issues such as incorrect PIN etc, I dont seem to be able to work around this problem.